# Changing visibility of java 8 default method

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8, overriding, default-method

I have a `class` (Say `FOO`) and it has a method with `default` visibility,
like below :

```
void sayHi() {}
```

Now, If a override this method in extending class I cannot decrease it's visibility. So I can only use `default` or `public`.

```
public class MyClassTest extends FOO {
    @Override
    // Or I can use public void sayHi()
    void sayHi() {
        System.out.println("Overriden sayHi");
    }
}
```

Now if I write an Interface in Java 8 with a default method like below :

```
public interface InterfaceX {

    // Java-8 defalu method
    default String printName() {
        System.out.println("Interface1 default metod");
        return "Interface1 default metod";
    }
}
```

Now, if I override this method in a class It should compile if a keep overridden method's visibility `default`.

```
public class Java8InterfaceTest implements InterfaceX{
    @Override
     void printHello() {
        System.out.println("Printing..!");
        Interface1.super.printName();
    }
 }
```

It says

> Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from InterfaceX

I already know that every method in `interface` in `public` by default, but in the above example we are using `default` which I think is one of the `access modifier` in `java`.

**I have following questions:**

1. Is `default` in `interface` different from `default` visibility which is provide when no access modifier applied?
2. If it's different then how it's different?

Comment: Why down-voted? It might be an silly questions but still I think it is a confusing question.

Comment: I can imagine you got that for lack of prior research. And just for the record: I reworked my answer. Hopefully you find it more helpful by now. Because honestly: as correct as the two other answers are - they miss the *real* problem in your whole question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`default` has nothing to do with default visibility. A `default` method in an interface is a method that has a default implementation within the interface.

The visibility of that method is still `public`.

Therefore the method implemented in your `Java8InterfaceTest` class must have `public` visibility:

```
public void printHello() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: So, are there two `default`s : one is for `interface default method` and one is for visibility?

Comment: @MehrajMalik the `default` keyword is never used in Java for default visibility. Default visibility has no keyword in Java.

Comment: @MehrajMalik *"So, are there two defaults"* - Yes and No. We have only one *key word* `default` which is connected to the *default method in  an interface* and we have the *default visibility* where we have no keyword at all.

Comment: @Eran `If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private)` as per java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: @MehrajMalik I didn't say there's no default visibility in Java. I said default visibility has no keyword, and therefore not related to the `default` keyword.

Comment: @Eran It seems that I've been confused with `no modifier` to `default`.. OMG... We all have been taught it's `default` ... **OH GOD! WHAT A  SURPRISE**

Comment: @MehrajMalik: it rather seems that you have been confused by the fact that all Java keywords have a literal meaning in the English language. There is also the concept of a “default constructor” which is entirely unrelated to the `default` keyword. Further, “default behavior”, found in a lot of specifications, is unrelated to said keyword. Unlike annotation default values, which use the `default` keyword but still are unrelated to `default` methods.

Answer (score 4):

I think that if you write your interface as :

```
interface Test {
    default public void go() {

    }
}
```

it would make sense. `default` methods are still `public`; nothing to do with "default" visibility.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers nicely outline that "syntactical" flaw in your assumption about *default* being a "visibility" thing.

But there is a conceptual problem behind that worth a dedicated answer: it is not **sound** to reduce the visibility of methods.

Keep in mind: the pubic "API" of a class or an interface declares a **contract** for client code to work with. Like: having a method `eat()` on a base class/interface `Animal`.

The whole point is that different subclasses/implementations can provide their own implementation of `eat()`. So that you can have:

```
Animal whatever = ...
whatever.eat();
```

And no matter what `...` is actually creating (could be `Cat`, `Dog`, `Unicorn`) - it is valid to call `whatever.eat()`.

Your idea is to say: I want to "hide" `eat()` for a specific subclass `Donkey`. If you could do that - all of a sudden the above code might be invalid. Because `whatever.eat()` is no longer a valid call when `whatever` happens to be an instance of `Donkey`.

Long story short: read about the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) to understand why "taking away" public is not a good idea - completely independent from mixing up "default package protected visibility" and
the default keyword in interfaces.